# Class in Processing can't reach another class

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception, processing

We are programming a jump and run game in processing which is java based. We have 12 classes and a main sketch. In the class game we describe the states of the game and what is supposed to happen when that game state happens. There is a problem with our player, in the class player we defined when the player dies and that the state game-state Lose is supposed to happen. But it seems, that the class player can't reach the definition of that game-state in the class game.

We are also getting the error NullPointerException.

```
-----------------------class Game----------------------

class Game
{
  // Eigenschaften
  private Level1 level1;
  private Player p;
  private Level2 level2;
  private Level3 level3;

  PImage start;
  public String gameState;

  public boolean left, right, up, down, space;
  public FrameObject camera, gameWorld;

  public boolean intersectHaus;

  PImage win;
  PImage gameover;
  public Enemy [] enemies;
  public Blume [] blumen;

  PImage spring;

  public int lives;

  // Konstruktor
  Game()
  {
    size(1400, 750);
    this.p = new Player();


    this.start = loadImage("start.png");
    this.win = loadImage("win.png");
    this.gameover = loadImage("gameover.png");

    this.spring = loadImage ("level2.png");



    this.gameState = "START";
    this.level1 = new Level1(this);
    this.level2 = new Level2(this);
    this.level3 = new Level3(this);

    this.lives = 3;
  }


  // Methoden

  void display()
  {
    this.p.leben();

    switch(this.gameState)
    {
    case "START":
    println("start funktioniert");
      startGame();
      break;
    case "PLAY1":
    println("play1 funktioniert");
      playGame();
      break;
    case "WIN":
    println("win funktioniert");  
      winGame();
      break;
    case "WIN2":
      winGame2();
      break;
    case "WIN3":
      winGame3();
      break;
    case "LOSE":
    println("lose hat funktioniert");
      loseGame();
      break;
    case "PLAY2":
      playGame2();
      break;
    case "PLAY3":
      playGame3();
      break;
    }
  }


  void startGame()
  {
    image(this.start, 0, 0);
    if (mousePressed == true)
    {
      klick.play();
      gameState = "PLAY1";
    }
  }

  void playGame()
  {
    this.level1.display();
  }

  void playGame2()
  {
    this.level2.display();
  }

  void playGame3()
  {
    this.level3.display();
  }

  void winGame2()
  {
    image(this.win, 0, 0);
    if (mousePressed == true)
    {
      klick.play();

      if (mousePressed == true)
      {
        klick.play();
        gameState = "PLAY3";
      }
    }
  }
  void winGame3()
  {
    image(this.win, 0, 0);
    if (mousePressed == true)
    {
      klick.play();
      gameState = "START";
      this.level1.reset();
    }
  }

  void winGame()
  {
    image(this.win, 0, 0);
    if (mousePressed == true)
    {
      klick.play();

      if (mousePressed == true)
      {
        klick.play();
        gameState = "PLAY2";
        this.level2.reset();
      }
    }
  }

  void loseGame()
  {
    //noLoop();
    
    image(this.gameover, 0, 0);
    if (mousePressed == true)
    {
      klick.play();
      gameState = "START";
      this.level1.reset();
    }
  }
  
  public void setGameState(String state)
  {
    this.gameState = state;
  }
  
  public Player getPlayer()
  {
    return this.p;
  }
}


---------------------class Level3---------------------
class Level3
{
  private Player p;
  private Blume [] blumen;
  private Wabe [] waben;
  private GiftBlume [] giftBlumen;
  private Haus h;
  private FrameObject camera, gameWorld;
  public ImageObject backImage;
  public ImageObject backImage1;
  public ImageObject backImage2;
  PImage hintergrund;
  PImage background;
  private Game parent;

  PImage hintergrund1;
  private Enemy [] enemies;
  PImage haus;

  private int score;

  //Konstruktor

  Level3(Game parent)
  {
    size(1400, 750);
    this.parent = parent;
    this.score = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < plattformen.length; i++)
    {
      plattformen[i] = loadImage("blume"+i+".png");
    }


    left = false;
    right = false;
    up = false;
    down = false;
    space = false;


    this.p = this.parent.getPlayer();

    this.blumen = new Blume[8];
    this.blumen[0] = new Blume(plattformen[15], 10, 550, 200, 25, "safe");
    this.blumen[1] = new Blume(plattformen[14], 700, 200, 200, 25, "safe");
    this.blumen[2] = new Blume(plattformen[13], 1100, 460, 200, 25, "safe");
    this.blumen[3] = new Blume(plattformen[12], 2000, 240, 170, 25, "safe");
    this.blumen[4] = new Blume(plattformen[17], 2500, 450, 200, 25, "safe");
    this.blumen[5] = new Blume(plattformen[15], 3700, 550, 200, 25, "safe");
    this.blumen[6] = new Blume(plattformen[14], 4000, 200, 200, 25, "safe");
    this.blumen[7] = new Blume(plattformen[13], 4100, 460, 200, 25, "safe");



    this.giftBlumen = new GiftBlume[4]; //
    this.giftBlumen [0] = new GiftBlume(1450, 420, 290, 25, "death");
    this.giftBlumen [1] = new GiftBlume(3000, 420, 290, 25, "death");
    this.giftBlumen [2] = new GiftBlume(3400, 420, 290, 25, "death");
    this.giftBlumen [3] = new GiftBlume(4800, 420, 290, 25, "death");


    this.waben = new Wabe[47];
    this.waben[0] = new Wabe(430, 100, 30, 30); //nach Blume 1
    this.waben[1] = new Wabe(430, 150, 30, 30);
    this.waben[2] = new Wabe(430, 200, 30, 30);
    this.waben[3] = new Wabe(430, 250, 30, 30);
    this.waben[4] = new Wabe(430, 300, 30, 30);

    this.waben[5] = new Wabe(960, 130, 30, 30); // nach Blume 2
    this.waben[6] = new Wabe(990, 160, 30, 30);
    this.waben[7] = new Wabe(1020, 190, 30, 30);
    this.waben[8] = new Wabe(1050, 220, 30, 30);
    this.waben[9] = new Wabe(1080, 250, 30, 30);
    this.waben[10] = new Wabe(1110, 280, 30, 30);

    this.waben[11] = new Wabe(1540, 160, 30, 30); // Blume 4
    this.waben[12] = new Wabe(1540, 100, 30, 30);
    this.waben[13] = new Wabe(1540, 220, 30, 30);

    this.waben[14] = new Wabe(2070, 160, 30, 30); // Blume 6
    this.waben[15] = new Wabe(2070, 60, 30, 30);
    this.waben[16] = new Wabe(2040, 110, 30, 30);
    this.waben[17] = new Wabe(2100, 110, 30, 30);

    this.waben[18] = new Wabe(2770, 300, 30, 30); // nach Blume 6
    this.waben[19] = new Wabe(2820, 300, 30, 30);
    this.waben[20] = new Wabe(2870, 300, 30, 30);
    this.waben[21] = new Wabe(2920, 300, 30, 30);

    this.waben[22] = new Wabe(3000, 80, 30, 30); // über Blume 7 & 8
    this.waben[23] = new Wabe(3050, 80, 30, 30);
    this.waben[24] = new Wabe(3100, 80, 30, 30);
    this.waben[25] = new Wabe(3150, 80, 30, 30);
    this.waben[26] = new Wabe(3200, 80, 30, 30);
    this.waben[27] = new Wabe(3250, 80, 30, 30);
    this.waben[28] = new Wabe(3300, 80, 30, 30);
    this.waben[29] = new Wabe(3350, 80, 30, 30);
    this.waben[30] = new Wabe(3400, 80, 30, 30);
    this.waben[31] = new Wabe(3450, 80, 30, 30);
    this.waben[32] = new Wabe(3500, 80, 30, 30);
    this.waben[33] = new Wabe(3550, 80, 30, 30);


    this.waben[34] = new Wabe(3700, 450, 30, 30); // Blume 9
    this.waben[35] = new Wabe(3750, 450, 30, 30);
    this.waben[36] = new Wabe(3800, 450, 30, 30);
    this.waben[37] = new Wabe(3850, 450, 30, 30);
    this.waben[38] = new Wabe(3900, 450, 30, 30);


    this.waben[39] = new Wabe(4400, 200, 30, 30); // nach Blume 11
    this.waben[40] = new Wabe(4450, 200, 30, 30);
    this.waben[41] = new Wabe(4500, 200, 30, 30);
    this.waben[42] = new Wabe(4550, 200, 30, 30);
    this.waben[43] = new Wabe(4600, 200, 30, 30);
    this.waben[44] = new Wabe(4650, 200, 30, 30);
    this.waben[45] = new Wabe(4600, 150, 30, 30);
    this.waben[46] = new Wabe(4600, 250, 30, 30);






    hintergrund1 = loadImage("hintergrund3.png");
    backImage2 = new ImageObject(0, 0, 1400, 750, hintergrund1);
    gameWorld = new FrameObject(0, 0, backImage2.w*4, backImage2.h);
    camera = new FrameObject(0, 0, width, height);

    this.h = new Haus();



    this.enemies = new Enemy [this.blumen.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.blumen.length; i++) {
      this.enemies[i] = new Enemy (this.blumen[i]);
    }

    camera.x = (gameWorld.x + gameWorld.w/2) - camera.w/2;
    camera.y = (gameWorld.y + gameWorld.h/2) - camera.h/2;
  }


  //Methoden


  void display ()
  {
    this.p.update();

    for (int i = 0; i < this.blumen.length; ++ i) // für nicht sichere Plattform
    {
      this.p.collisionSide = rectangleCollisions(this.p, this.blumen[i]);
      if (this.p.collisionSide != "none" && this.blumen[i].typeof == "death")
      {
        this.p.leben();
      }
      this.p.checkBlumen();
    }

    //Kamerabeewgung
    camera.x = floor(p.x + (p.halfWidth) - (camera.w/2));
    camera.y = floor(p.y + (p.halfHeight) - (camera.h/2));

    if (camera.x < gameWorld.x)
    {
      camera.x = gameWorld.x;
    }
    if (camera.y < gameWorld.y)
    {
      camera.y = gameWorld.y;
    }

    if (camera.x + camera.w > gameWorld.x + gameWorld.w)
    {
      camera.x = gameWorld.x + gameWorld.w - camera.w;
    }
    if (camera.y + camera.h > gameWorld.h)
    {
      camera.y = gameWorld.h - camera.h;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this.enemies.length; i++) {
      this.enemies[i].update();
      if (rectangleCollisionPvE(this.p, this.enemies[i]) && !this.enemies[i].dead) {

        this.enemies[i].deathJump();
      }
    }

    pushMatrix();
    translate(-camera.x, -camera.y);

    this.backImage2.display();
    this.p.display();

    for (int i = 0; i < this.blumen.length; ++i)
    {
      this.blumen[i].display();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this.giftBlumen.length; ++i) //
    {
      this.giftBlumen[i].display();
      if (intersectGiftBlume(this.p, this.giftBlumen[i]) == true)
      {
        this.p.lebenGift();
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < waben.length; ++i)
    {
      this.waben[i].display();
      if (intersect(this.p, this.waben[i]) == true)
      {
        this.waben[i].caught();
        this.score ++;
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this.enemies.length; i++) {
      this.enemies[i].display();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this.haus.width/2; i ++)
      this.h.display();

    if (intersectHaus(this.p, this.h) == true)
    {

      image(this.hintergrund, 200, 200);


      this.parent.setGameState("WIN3");
    }



    popMatrix();

    fill(255);
    String s = "Score: " + score;
    textSize(20);
    text(s, 1270, 50);
    //textFont(Font1);
    textSize(20);
    text("Steuerung:", 60, 50);
    textSize(18);
    text("space - springen, a - links, d - rechts", 60, 70);

    this.p.leben();
  }



  boolean intersect(Player p, Wabe w)
  {
    float distance = dist(p.x, p.y, w.x, w.y);
    if (distance < (p.w/2 + w.w/2))
    {
      return true;
    } else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  boolean intersectGiftBlume(Player p, GiftBlume g) //
  {
    float distance = dist(p.x, p.y, g.x, g.y);
    if (distance < (p.w/2 + g.w/2))
    {
      return true;
    } else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }


  boolean intersectHaus(Player p, Haus h)
  {
    float distance = dist(p.x, p.y, h.x, h.y);
    if (distance < (p.w/2 + h.w/2))
    {
      return true;
    } else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  boolean rectangleCollisionPvE (Player r1, Enemy r2) {
    float dx = (r1.x + r1.w/2) - (r2.x + r2.w/2);
    float dy = (r1.y + r1.h/2) - (r2.y + r2.h/2);

    float combinedHalfWidths = r1.halfWidth + r2.halfWidth;
    float combinedHalfHeights = r1.halfHeight + r2.halfHeight;

    if (abs(dx)< combinedHalfWidths) {
      if (abs(dy)< combinedHalfHeights) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }


  String rectangleCollisions(Player r1, Blume r2)
  {
    if (r1.vy < 0) // ausklammern um nicht von unten durch die Blume springen
    {
      return "none";
    }

    float dx = (r1.x + r1.w/2) - (r2.x + r2.w/2);
    float dy = (r1.y + r1.h/2) - (r2.y + r2.h/2);

    float combinedHalfWidths = r1.halfWidth + r2.halfWidth;
    float combinedHalfHeights = r1.halfHeight + r2.halfHeight;

    if (abs(dx) < combinedHalfWidths)
    {
      if (abs(dy) < combinedHalfHeights)
      {
        float overlapX = combinedHalfWidths - abs(dx);
        float overlapY = combinedHalfHeights - abs(dy);

        if (overlapX >= overlapY)
        {
          if (dy > 0)
          {
            r1.y += overlapY;
            return "top";
          } else
          {
            r1.y -= overlapY;
            return "bottom";
          }
        } else
        {
          if (dx > 0)
          {
            r1.x += overlapX;
            return "left";
          } else
          {
            r1.x -= overlapX;
            return "right";
          }
        }
      } else
      {
        return "none";
      }
    } else
    {
      return "none";
    }
  }
}

-------------------------- class Player-----------------------
class Player
{
  // Eigenschaften
  private float w, h, x, y, vx, vy, accelerationX, accelerationY, speedLimit; // acceleration = Beschleunigung
  private int lives;

  // world values
  private float friction, bounce, gravity;

  private boolean isOnGround;
  private float jumpForce;

  private float halfWidth, halfHeight;
  private String collisionSide;

  private boolean facingRight;
  public String gameState;
  private PImage player, player2;





  // Konstruktor
  Player()
  {
    this.init();
    this.lives = 3;
    this.player = loadImage("biene.png");
    this.player2 = loadImage("biene2.png");
  }

  void init()
  {
    this.w = 90; // an Biene anpassen!
    this.h = 65;
    this.x = 50; // - w/2;
    this.y = 10; //(gameWorld.y + gameWorld.h/2) - h/2;
    this.vx = 0;
    this.vy = 0;
    this.accelerationX = 0;
    this.accelerationY = 0;
    this.speedLimit = 15;
    this.isOnGround = false;
    this.jumpForce = -15; //Höhe Sprung

    // world values
    this.friction = 0.96;
    this.bounce = -0.2;
    this.gravity = 0.3;

    this.halfWidth = w/2;
    this.halfHeight = h/2;

    this.facingRight = true;


    this.collisionSide = "";
  }

  // Methoden
  void update()
  {
    //text("Leben: "+this.lives, 1000, 500);

    // start all moves off with friction at 1
    if (left && !right)
    {
      this.accelerationX = -0.2;
      this.friction = 1;
      this.facingRight = false;
    }
    if (right && !left)
    {
      this.accelerationX = 0.2;
      this.friction = 1;
      this.facingRight = true;
    }
    if (!left && !right)
    {
      this.accelerationX = 0;
    }
    if (up && !down && isOnGround) // <--- im Fall fliegen können
    {
      this.vy = this.jumpForce;
      this.isOnGround = false;
      this.friction = 1;
    }
    if (down && !up)
    {
      this.accelerationY = 0.2;
      this.friction = 1;
    }
    if (!up && !down)
    {
      this.accelerationY = 0;
    }
    // removing impulse reintroduces friction
    if (!up && !down && !left && !right)
    {
      this.friction = 0.96;
      this.gravity = 0.3; // Geschwindigkeit des Fallens
    }

    this.vx += this.accelerationX;
    this.vy += this.accelerationY;

    // friction 1 = no friction
    this.vx *= this.friction;
    this.vy *= this.friction;

    //apply gravity
    this.vy += this.gravity;

    // correct fpr max. speeds
    if (this.vx > this.speedLimit)
    {
      this.vx = this.speedLimit;
    }
    if (this.vx < -this.speedLimit)
    {
      this.vx = -this.speedLimit;
    }
    // need to let gravity ramp it up
    if (this.vy > 3* this.speedLimit) // Geschwindigkeit des Fallens
    {
      this.vy = 3 * this.speedLimit;
    }
    if (this.vy < -this.speedLimit)
    {
      this.vy = -this.speedLimit;
    }

    if (abs(vx) < 0.2)
    {
      this.vx = 0;
    }

    if (abs(vy) < 0.2)
    {
      this.vy = 0;
    }

    // move player
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;

    this.checkBoundaries();
    this.checkBlumen();

    //x = Math.max(0, Math.min(x + vx, gameWorld.w - w));
    //y = Math.max(0, Math.min(y + vy, gameWorld.h - h));
  } // Update Ende

  void checkBoundaries()
  {
    // left
    if (this.x < 0)
    {
      this.vx *= this.bounce;
      this.x = 0;
    }

    if (this.y < 0)
    {
      this.vy *= this.bounce;
      this.y = 0;
    }
  }


  void checkBlumen()
  {
    if (this.collisionSide == "bottom" && this.vy >= 0)
    {
      if (this.vy < 1)
      {
        this.isOnGround = true;
        this.vy = 0;
        println("top");
      } else
      {
        this.vy *= this.bounce/2;
      }
    } else if (this.collisionSide == "top" && this.vy <= 0)
    {
      this.vy = 0;
    } else if (this.collisionSide == "right" && this.vx >= 0)
    {
      this.vx = 0;
    } else if (this.collisionSide == "left" && this.vx <= 0)
    {
      this.vx = 0;
    }
    if (this.collisionSide != "bottom" && this.vy > 0)
    {
      this.isOnGround = false;
    }
  }

  void lebenGift()
  {
    this.init();
    this.lives --;
    if (this.lives <1)
    {
      gameState = "LOSE";
    }
  }

  void leben()
  {
    text("Leben: "+this.lives, 1270, 100);
    if (this.y + this.h > height)
    {
      this.init();
      this.lives--;
      if (this.lives <1)
      {
        gameState = "LOSE";
      }
    }
  }


  void display()
  {
    fill(0);
    //rect(x, y, w, h);
    if (facingRight)
    {
      image(this.player, x, y - 40);
    } else
    {
      image(this.player2, x, y - 40);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. There seem to be some code missing to let us reproduce the issue. [A minimal example is always better to get help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but if it's impossible for you to isolate the issue we would at least have a better chance at helping with complete, working code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer laancelot. We found our mistake. We needed a boolean in the class player which then needs to be called in the class game. It works now :)

Comment: The best course of action here would be to edit your question so it is answerable, then to post the answer yourself. This community works on two fronts: we try to help the person asking the question, and also to write questions and answers so that future users will be able to search and use them to solve their own problems. Not everybody comes back to answer their own questions, but it would be greatly appreciated. btw good job in finding the issue and solving it!